# Why does WQL LIKE operator not work on drive c, but works fine on drive d?

Tags: file, wmi, monitoring, wildcard, wql

I'm learning about File System Monitoring to speed up my 3rd and 4th backups of my mail server. I have a nice VB Script that works flawlessly on drive D, but when I query changes to drive C, nothing is returned if I use a wildcard.

Here are my queries:

This works fine for c:\sc, but does not return subfolder changes:

```
     Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent Within 10 Where TargetInstance Isa 'CIM_DataFile' And ((TargetInstance.Drive='c:' And TargetInstance.Path = '\\sc\\'))
```

This works fine for d:\sc, and does return subfolder changes:

```
     Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent Within 10 Where TargetInstance Isa 'CIM_DataFile' And ((TargetInstance.Drive='d:' And TargetInstance.Path LIKE '\\sc\\%'))
```

This one returns no changes at all. No error messages are returned, and the script continues to run:

```
     Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent Within 10 Where TargetInstance Isa 'CIM_DataFile' And ((TargetInstance.Drive='c:' And TargetInstance.Path LIKE '\\sc\\%'))
```

The double parenthesis are so that I can add similar queries connected with "OR".

My system drive is drive C.
Drive D is a removable USB drive.

Have I changed some setting on my system drive that is preventing this from working?
 Or perhaps the query is returning too many results?

I have been searching about this for a few hours. Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when you uses the `LIKE` operator in a WQL sentence with the [`CIM_DataFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387236%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class, the WMI scan for the full drive to find a match, now since you USB drive have a more small (and simple) tree folder structure the WMI can return the results more quickly. but when you uses the C drive the WMI still running the Query until find all the matches. So the recommendation is don't use the LIKE operator with `CIM_DataFile` , instead just use the `=` operator like so :

```
Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' And ((TargetInstance.Drive='c:' And TargetInstance.Path = '\\sc\\'))
```

P.D: If you are using the `LIKE` operator because you expect monitor changes in multiple folders, this is not possible, instead you must use one WQL and event watcher per folder.

Comment: Ok, sounds feasible, but correct me if I'm wrong - the drive is not being queried, but rather the event log. The second example I gave above works flawlessly for folders and subfolders on drive D:, which, incidentally, has backups of 4 different servers on it, making it neither small nor simple, so apparently it is possible to use LIKE to retrieve subfolder changes, right? Each file creation, deletion and change is being logged to the event log, so how do I query the event log for those events that occur on a folder and it's subfolders on drive c:?

Comment: C drive is typical Windows installation, D drive is 3 typical Windows installations and one Linux.

Comment: What you indicate not make sense to me, i have a lot of experience using the WMI, and the behavior which you describe does not fit with my personal experience on this topic. Anyway why you are using the `LIKE` operator?

Comment: My second example above returns the events for all files in the folder and all subfolders for drive D. Please try it on a secondary drive of yours and perhaps you will come to the same conclusion I have - it works in some cases. I have run the query from the third example above in the WMI tester, and interestingly enough, the query started, and the GUI never came back. So apparently, the query runs, and doesn't complete, and doesn't timeout, and doesn't raise an error such as Quota Limit or other.

Comment: Not sure why it occurs on C but not on D, but it appears to be a non-viable solution for monitoring drive C. I could map all folders and subscribe to their events, but there are approximately 8000 folders to watch, and that seems excessive.

Comment: I have just discovered an error that I made. The D drive, albeit containing 4 computers worth of information, does not have the entire directory tree exposed to the OS - therefore, it has a file system containing 36 files in 3 folders. When I make the rest of the tree available, it fails just as it does on C. So, were I to wait out the scanning of the entire tree (as your answer mentioned would happen), it would probably start returning results. I'm curious to know how long it takes, but by my measure, more than a few seconds is too long.